# What is the criteria for md-select to check duplicate options in md-options

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have been using Angular Material for a while in my project. While using md-select, I am stuck to a problem wherein I am getting Duplicate md-option values error.

I am aware that md-options takes unique values and I am assigning an array to md-options. This is however, an array of objects. So I would like to know what is the criteria that is used to differentiate objects. The API do not say much about it.

My use case demands to change md-options of an md-select, based on selection from another md-select. So I am watching the selection of first md-select and firing a watch on its change and updating md-options of second md-select.

Below is the approach I am using to assign array to md-options:

```
$scope.$watch('search.selectedTrades', function(newTrades, oldTrades) {
    if ((newTrades.length === 0)) {
        $rootScope.search.selectedTrades = oldTrades;
        return;
    }
    if ($rootScope.search.selectedTrades && $rootScope.search.selectedTrades.length > 0) {
        if (!$rootScope.identity.isClusterManager) {
            $rootScope.search.selectedTrades = newTrades;
            SearchFilterData.setSelectedTrades(newTrades);
            $rootScope.search.selectedClusters = [];
            $scope.clusters = [];
            $scope.subareas = [];
            var clusterKeys = [];
            $rootScope.search.selectedTrades.forEach(function(t) {
                t.lstClusters.forEach(function(c) {
                    if (clusterKeys.indexOf(c.ClusterKey) == -1) {
                        clusterKeys.push(c.ClusterKey);
                        $scope.clusters.push(c);
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    } else {
        $scope.clusters = [];
        $scope.subareas = [];
        $rootScope.search.selectedClusters = [];
        $rootScope.search.selectedSubAreas = [];
        SearchFilterData.setSelectedTrades($rootScope.search.selectedTrades);
    }
});
```

In above code, clusterKey is a unique entity for each object. So I am using it to push unique values into array.
This however happens on few random scenarios, after I have selected and de-selected various options. Please advise what I am doing wrong and what is the criteria for marking two objects duplicate

Comment: Any luck on getting this resolved?  I have the same scenario.

Comment: I am also getting 'Duplicate md-option values' exception.  I have verified that the array that is bound to the options list has no duplicate entries.

Answer (score 8):

You did not provide your markup, so I cannot be sure, but in my case the problem was caused by omitting the double curleys on the 'value' attribute in the md-option tag.

This is bad:  Notice the missing curly braces

```
<md-option ng-repeat="item in vm.list" value="item.id">{{item.text}}</md-option>
```

This is not:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="item in vm.itemlist" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.text}}</md-option>
```

I believe the reason that this fails is that each item will be placed into the option list will be given a value of 'item.id' (literally).  It will fail on the second iteration of the repeat.
Using the curly braces causes the value in 'item.id' to be used.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Try using ng-value instead of just value attribute.

```
<md-option ng-repeat="item in vm.list" ng-value="item.id">{{item.text}}</md-option>
```